# Pagination in search.php not working correctly (WordPress)

Tags: search, pagination

In the past few days I was trying to create a search.php template for results that contain my CPT. As long as the search works itself, pagination not. Every link in pagination redirects to 404. I was trying a lot of possibile solutions from Stack, FB and others but with no results.

Instead of showing to you my code which is obviously not working correctly, I thought how great would be when someone could paste here a tested by himself a simple search.php template which contain CPT in results and with working pagination? Then I could compare with my code and find a solution for this annoying popular issue

Thanks!

edit:

If someone is curious, this is my current search.php:

```
<div class="center">
                    <?php
                    // Define custom query parameters
$custom_query_args = array( 
                            'post_type'     => array('drzewa_formowane', 'pre_bonsai'),
                            'post_status'   => 'publish',
                            'order'         => 'asc',
                            's'             => $s,
                            'paged'         => $paged
                        
);
// Get current page and append to custom query parameters array
$custom_query_args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
// Instantiate custom query
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );
// Pagination fix
$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $custom_query;
// Output custom query loop
if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
        $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <?php include 'product.php' ?>
                        <?    endwhile;
endif;
// Reset postdata
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                            <nav class="pagination">
                                <?php
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'prev_next'          => true,
    'prev_text'          => __(' « '),
    'next_text'          => __(' » '),
    'type'               => 'plain',
) ); ?>
                            </nav>
                            <?php
// Reset main query object
$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query;
                    ?>
                </div>
```

I was also trying with simple

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

without WP_Query and I was trying include CPT to search results via "pre_get_posts" but then was no results from my CPT...

Comment: Related – https://stackoverflow.com/a/44262584/1454514

Comment: I was trying that also and it wont work in my case.

Comment: I know you said you are looking for a working example, but the community might help better if you post a snippet of code.

Comment: I've edited my post above.